# how to prevent firebase to show one message multiple time

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase to chat messaging. Where when I submit the form for sent messages, all messages are repeated and fetched from start to beginning. Here see a image below to better understanding.
[image]

Here is the code what i am actually doing.

```
user_chats.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                user_messages.push(doc.data());
            });
            showMessages();
        });
function showMessages()
    {
        for (let i =0;i<user_messages.length;i++)
        {
            let user_id = user_messages[i].user_id;
            if (user_id == auth_id)
            {
                let selector = $('#my_msg .row');
                selector.find('.chat').text(user_messages[i].message);
                selector.clone().appendTo('.msg_area_div');
            }
            else{
                let selector = $('#user_msg .row');
                selector.find('.chat').text(user_messages[i].message);
                selector.clone().appendTo('.msg_area_div');
            }
        }
    }
```

**Here I want to show the only new items which is pushed not all the older message**
Help me solve this problem. **TIA**

**Edited**

After using the solution of **@Frank van Puffelen**

```
function fetchMessage() {
            let document_id = documentID();

        let table = db.collection("chat").doc(document_id).collection('chats');
        let user_chats = table.orderBy('created_at');

        user_chats.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
                if (change.type === "added") {
                    user_messages.push(change.doc.data());
                }
            });
            showMessages();
        });
    }
    function showMessages() {
        $('.msg_area_div').empty();
        for (let i = 0; i < user_messages.length; i++) {
            let active_user_id = user_messages[i].user_id;

            if (active_user_id == auth_id) {
                let selector = $('#my_msg .row');
                selector.find('.chat').text(user_messages[i].message);
                selector.clone().appendTo('.msg_area_div');
            } else {
                let selector = $('#user_msg .row');
                selector.find('.chat').text(user_messages[i].message);
                selector.clone().appendTo('.msg_area_div');
            }
        }
        scrollDown();
    }
```

got the result like these
[image]

Comment: maybe you have to clear the `.msg_area_div` before appending messages, since `showMessages` will be called multiple times.

Comment: tried $('.msg_area_div').empty(); before for loop ...but no luck

Comment: check `user_messages` and `querySnapshot`, may be snapshot brings all messages and you are appending all of them to user_messages every time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looping over the `QuerySnapshot` itself, you're always seeing all documents inside your loop - even if there was only a single change to the snapshot.

This is a valid option, but it means you'll need to clear-and-rebuild the entire chat node each time your `onSnapshot` gets called. You can do this by clearing the HTML in your `showMessages` by clearing `.msg_area_div` before adding the messages with:

```
$('.msg_area_div').empty();
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the lower-level properties to [process only the documents that were added, changed or deleted](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) with:

```
snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
    if (change.type === "added") {
        console.log("New city: ", change.doc.data());
    }
    if (change.type === "modified") {
        console.log("Modified city: ", change.doc.data());
    }
    if (change.type === "removed") {
        console.log("Removed city: ", change.doc.data());
    }
});
```

Comment: ok @Frank van Pufflen i will try and update you and thanks for the answer

Comment: i used your alternative solution but still shows me the repeated messages

Comment: i used your alternative solution but still shows me the repeated messages....I mean its working fine while chatting with one of my friend....But some times it loads the same message twice..like i send you hi and then hello...the it prints hi twice and then hello

Comment: check i have updated my post

Comment: When you attach a listener with `onSnapshot `, its `snapshot.docChanges()` will initially have only `change.type === "added"` events - and on subsequent calls it will contain only the delta from the initial snapshot. Is that not what is happening for you?

Comment: i think no. Otherwise, why it shows me the message twice. For better understanding what's happening there i updated my post with the latest code. Please take a look

Comment: but on thing i always doesn't get the same problem. It happens some time

Comment: I've never seen the SDK fire with the entire document set multiple times, but it could of course be an edge case yuo're hitting. Can you reproduce the problem in a site like jsbin/stackblitz, so I can take a look at it?